# How to transpose a single item in a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested, syntax-error

I am trying to input values into my table but the table is not coming out the way I would like it to. The headers ("OrderDate", "Rep", etc.) of my given csv file should be under the "Columns:" cell in the following image: [Table of statistical values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlouc.png)

I have tried to create multiple functions that could transpose the headers but when trying to print the table, it would give the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__.
```

One code I tired to input just before the "labels" line was:

```
headers2 = [x.split() for x in headers]
```

P.S. I have removed the csv file code and manually put in a list assigned to "A".

**My Code:**

```
A = [['OrderDate', 'Region', 'Rep', 'Item', 'Units', 'Unit Price'], 
['4-Jul-2014', 'East', 'Richard', 'Pen Set', '62', '4.99'], 
['12-Jul-2014', 'East', 'Nick', 'Binder', '29', '1.99'], 
['21-Jul-2014', 'Central', 'Morgan', 'Pen Set', '55', '12.49'], 
['29-Jul-2014', 'East', 'Susan', 'Binder', '81', '19.99'], 
['7-Aug-2014', 'Central', 'Matthew', 'Pen Set', '42', '23.95'], 
['15-Aug-2014', 'East', 'Richard', 'Pencil', '35', '4.99'], 
['24-Aug-2014', 'West', 'James', 'Desk', '3', '275'], 
['1-Sep-2014', 'Central', 'Smith', 'Desk', '2', '125']]

minVal = []
maxVal = []
hist = []
average = []
stanDev = []
mode = []
headers = A[0] #this sets the variable "headers" as the first row 
rows = A[1:] #sets the variable 'rows' to be a nested list without headers

def rows2cols(A):
    if len(A) == 0: #this covers the base case of having an empty csv file
        return [] 
    res  = [[] for x in headers] #creates a list of empty lists
    for line in A: 
        for col in range(len(line)): 
            res[col].append(line[col])  
    return res

def convertstringtofloats(A):
    res = []
    for x in A:
        res.append(float(x))
    return res

def isnumericlist(A):
    for x in A:
        try:
            numeric = float(x)
        except:
            return False
    return True

def getMin(A):
    B = convertstringtofloats(cols[col]) #Let's Python know what B is for the next line. If this isn't here, there is an error.
    res = B[0] 
    for x in A:
        if x < res:
            res = x
    return res

def getMax(A):
    B = convertstringtofloats(cols[col]) #Let's Python know what B is for the next line. If this isn't here, there is an error.
    res = B[0]
    for x in A:
        if x > res:
            res = x
    return res

def getAvg(A):
    return sum(A)/len(A)

def most_common(A):
    counts = {}
    for x in A:
        counts[(x)] = counts.get((x), 0) + 1  
    max = -1
    maxKey = ""
    for key,value in counts.items():
        if max < value:
            max = value
            maxKey = key
    return maxKey

def getSD(A):
    sumsq = 0
    for n in A:
        sumsq += (getAvg(A))**2
    return sumsq

cols = rows2cols(rows) #transposes 'rows' and assigns to variable 'cols'

def stats(A):
    B = convertstringtofloats(A)
    minVal.append(getMin(B))
    maxVal.append(getMax(B))
    average.append(getAvg(B))
    stanDev.append(getSD(B))


for col in range(len(headers)):
    if isnumericlist(cols[col]):
        stats(cols[col]) #calls the function to calculate stats of the transposed matrix
    else:
        minVal.append("n/a")
        maxVal.append("n/a")
        average.append("n/a")
        stanDev.append("n/a")
    mode.append(most_common(cols[col]))

#headers2 = [x.split() for x in headers]
labels = ["Columns:", "Min", "Max", "Avg", "Std. Dev.", "Most Common Word"] #labels for the table

table_values = [labels, headers, minVal, maxVal, average, stanDev, mode] #combines all the calculated stats into a single list

print(table_values)

def print_table(table):
    longest_cols = [
        (max([len(str(row[i])) for row in table]) + 0) for i in range(len(table[0]))
    ]
    row_format = "|".join([" {:>" + str(longest_col) + "} " for longest_col in longest_cols])
    first = True
    for row in table:
        print(row_format.format(*row))
        if first:
            print((sum(longest_cols) + (len(table[0]) - 0) * 3) * "-")
            first = False

print_table(table_values) # this prints the 'labels' at the top, but the statistical values are not in the right place
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Bob I'm sorry to say, but based on your description, it is unclear to me at least what kind of output you expect or need.